# Vitest - Configuration Not Excluding file from Test Coverage in Sveltekit Project

Tags: svelte, vitest

I'm currently working on a Svelte project with vitest for testing, and I'm facing an issue with excluding a specific file, myfile.js, from the test coverage. Despite configuring vitest with the exclude option, the file is still being included in the coverage report.

**vitest.config.js**

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import svelte from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [svelte({ hot: !process.env.VITEST })],
  test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: 'jsdom',
    setupFiles: ['src/setupTest.js'],
    coverage: {
      reporter: ['text', 'lcov'],
      all: true
    },
    exclude: ['myFile.js', '**/node_modules/**', '**/dist/**']
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `exclude` or the `include` attribute under the `coverage` option. I would suggest using the `include` attribute because it is easier to configure:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import { svelte } from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [svelte()],
  test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: 'jsdom',
    coverage: {
      include: ['src/**']
    }
  }
});
```

Initially, it does not exclude your `myfile.js` (or in my case the `svelte.config.js`) file because of the `coverage.include` option default value is `['**']` which includes all the files from the root folder.

I got the following coverage output that includes everything that is under the `src` folder:

```
npm run coverage

...

 % Coverage report from v8
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File           | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files      |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 | 
 lib           |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 | 
  index.js     |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 | 1
 routes        |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 | 
  +page.svelte |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 | 1-2
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```

See the [coverage config](https://vitest.dev/config/#coverage) option default values and its various attributes for more detail.